# How can I create identicons using Java or Android?

Tags: java, android, identicon

I've seen many questions about this, but all of them are C#. None of them are Java, and I couldn't find a proper library for this.

[image]

What library can do this for me programmatically by giving it a string/hash? This algorithm is actually implemented on StackExchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

I used Gravatar. I first got the link of the image and stored it as a `String` like this:

```
String identiconURL = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + userID + "?s=55&d=identicon&r=PG";
```

Then, I used Glide:

```
Glide.with(ProfilePictureChooserActivity.this)
      .load(identiconURL)
      .centerCrop()
      .into(imageView);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can look at this link. There is a code that you could use to generate your identicons http://www.davidhampgonsalves.com/Identicons

The code for Java is the following one:

```
public static BufferedImage generateIdenticons(String text, int image_width, int image_height){
        int width = 5, height = 5;

        byte[] hash = text.getBytes();

        BufferedImage identicon = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        WritableRaster raster = identicon.getRaster();

        int [] background = new int [] {255,255,255, 0};
        int [] foreground = new int [] {hash[0] & 255, hash[1] & 255, hash[2] & 255, 255};

        for(int x=0 ; x < width ; x++) {
            //Enforce horizontal symmetry
            int i = x < 3 ? x : 4 - x;
            for(int y=0 ; y < height; y++) {
                int [] pixelColor;
                //toggle pixels based on bit being on/off
                if((hash[i] >> y & 1) == 1)
                    pixelColor = foreground;
                else
                    pixelColor = background;
                raster.setPixel(x, y, pixelColor);
            }
        }

        BufferedImage finalImage = new BufferedImage(image_width, image_height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

        //Scale image to the size you want
        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();
        at.scale(image_width / width, image_height / height);
        AffineTransformOp op = new AffineTransformOp(at, AffineTransformOp.TYPE_NEAREST_NEIGHBOR);
        finalImage = op.filter(identicon, finalImage);

        return finalImage;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. That link provides the use for plain Java and not for android which could confuse future readers. Give an example and make the generated bitmap set to an imageview

Comment: I'll do it soon. Thanks for the hint. I'm new to being an active user on Stack Overflow.